# Login failed for user 'user' when trying to connect to a Azure Sql Database

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, powershell, ssms

I tried in a few different ways to connect to an Azure Sql Database, but every try in powershell failed.

This is my first try using a connection string which results in: Login failed for user 'user'. error

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer

$connString = 'Server=tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={db};User ID={usr}@{server};Password={pwd};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connString -Query "SELECT 'Hello world!'"
```

Second try, same error:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'tcp:{db}.database.windows.net,1433' -Database '{db}' -Username '{usr}' -Password '{pwd}' -Query "SELECT 'Hello world!'"
```

Third try with PSCredentials, same error:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '{pwd}' -AsPlainText -Force
$mssqlCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('{usr}', $password)

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433' -Database '{db}' -Credential $mssqlCredentials -Query "SELECT 'Hello world!'"
```

I also tried using Invoke-SqlCmd2 module, but no luck, same error:

```
Import-Module Invoke-SqlCmd2

$connString = 'Server=tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={db};User ID={usr}@{server};Password={pwd};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;'

Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -SQLConnection $connString -Query "SELECT 'Hello world!'"
```

I want to mention connecting using SSMS or using python jupyter notebook with sqlachemy works without any issue:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

conn_str = f"mssql+pymssql://[usr]:[pwd]@[server].database.windows.net:1433/[db]"
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=False)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT 'Hello world!'"))
    print(result.all())
```

A lot of answers suggest that I need to change the password if it contains special characters, although the only special character I use is '§' and it's not feasible to change the password due to the fact that the account is used in a lot of other different processes.

And I also don't want to introduce a new scripting language in our stack, so hopefully some knows a way to bypass this everlasting issue.

**Later Edit**: I'm starting to believe it is an ODBC driver issue. Since python uses it's own driver for SQL Server and it works on python. And I also tried on a different remote machine and the powershell scripts are working. I'm still not sure what's the issue. I tried to install a few missing sql drivers that I thought they might fix the issue, but with no luck.

These are the drivers from my local machine:

[local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paPgP.png)

And these are the drivers from the remote machine:

[remote machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgFFB.png)

Comment: Check the log files in SQL Server to get more info.  Check the user and group names.  The database may not accept the user/group that you are using.  The log can be found using SQL Server Management Studio in the explorer under Management.  Then check permission of the database to see if user has access.  Also when you login using SSMS check login GUI if the credentials is windows or SQL Server.  Windows doesn't use a username and password and connection string for Windows has to have "Integrated Security - True"

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined usr and pwd before as

```
$usr="yourUser"
$pwd="§yourPassword§"
```

the line

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '{pwd}' -AsPlainText -Force
```

should be

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
```

means then you need to replace the Variables '{usr/pwd}' with $usr/$pwd

This should work:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer
$usr = "yourUser"
$pwd = "abc§123AAA"
$db = "yourDatabase"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force

$password = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($usr, $password)

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433' -Database $db -Credential $mssqlCredentials -Query "SELECT 'Hello world!'"
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. That's my way of defining a placeholder for the actual hardcoded value so I won't publish my credentials on internet, it's not a variable. So when I say '{pwd}', what I'm trying to say is 'here is the password'.

Comment: Also, just for the record. I tried to move the hardcoded values into their one variables per your example and I'm still facing the 'Login failed for user 'user'' error.

Comment: I assume that the user has login rights and is not disabled, because you said mentioned that "connecting using SSMS or using python jupyter notebook with sqlachemy works without any issue."
Do you have access to the AzureSQL-Logfiles and is there anything present about the "connection-try"?